# Updating PROJ GEOS and GDAL in R

Tags: raster, r, proj, rgdal, rgeos

I have been having trouble linking to `GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.0`. I have tried reinstalling `sf, rgdal, raster, and rgeos` packages. I still couldn't link to `GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.0`. I'm only able to `Link to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3`. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: There are a few links in this thread that discuss installation and compliation of sf and related system libraries that may be useful for you: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-configure-error-libproj-not-found-in-standard-or-given-locations-when-installing-sf-on-macos/58787/19?u=mfherman